# how to instantiate an object based on

Tags: java, list, generics

I want to instantiate an object based on the type of the list(that is Truck) and add to the list, I try something below, but it warns me with "sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl incompatible with java.lang.Class"

```
public <T extends Car> void addRow(List<T> list) {
Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) list.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
T newInstance = clazz.newInstance();
list.add(newInstance);
}
```

method call:

```
List<Truck> abc = new ArrayList<Truck>;
addRow(abc);
```

any help? Tks all in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Because of type erasure, you can't do this. See, for instance, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71585/how-to-get-parametrized-class-instance) or [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java). The best you can do is either a factory class or to pass the Class instance as a separate parameter:

```
addRow(abc, Truck.class);
```

More info on type erasure can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Answer (score 0):

Or if you're making all the types, you could make a method similar to clone() but which makes default instances and override the method in all classes.