# Is it possible to obtain an instance of Class<SomeGenericClass<SomeType>>

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to obtain an instance of `Class<SomeGenericClass<SomeType>>`?

For example an instance of `Class<ArrayList<String>>` without instantiating an instance of `ArrayList<String>`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T castToGeneric(Object objectToCast, T typeInferrenceClass) {
    return (T)objectToCast;
}

// usage

Object someObject = null /* initialised elsewhere */;
List<String> listOfStrings = castToGeneric(someObject, new ArrayList<String>());

// I want to avoid having to create - new ArrayList<String>();
```

I know this code is ugly and I shouldn't be doing this. But we are where we are...

Comment: Just to be clear, you are obtaining an instance of `Class`, the rest is just annotations for the compiler.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes - I want an instance of a Class

Comment: @gasan have you tried compiling what you typed?

Comment: List is an interface, not a class. You can only get a Class from an ArrayList, for example.

Comment: @RobertKovačević False. Every type in Java has its `Class` instance, even `int.class`.

Comment: @loudsight, sorry it seems that you cant call .class on generic type. I've added an answer for you.

Comment: maybe Collections.<String>emptyList(); will help? (you won't instantiate additional objects). But it internally makes a class cast.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this workaround to your problem:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T castToGeneric(Object objectToCast) {
    return (T)objectToCast;
}

// usage

Object someObject = null /* initialised elsewhere */;
Class<ArrayList<String>> listOfStrings = <Class<ArrayList<String>>>castToGeneric(someObject);
```

so instead of passing type as a parameter, you're passing it as a type-parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If want to instantiating `Class<SomeGenericClass<SomeType>>`

```
Class<List<Object>> list = (Class<List<Object>>)(Class<?>)List.class;

Type genericclass = new ArrayList<Object>() {}.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
```

Comment: Please illustrate how do you create "theClass" parameter passed into your method. When T is List<String>?

Comment: OP specifically asked for a solution **without instantiating** and your first line emits unchecked cast warnings. I kind of think OP is already aware of half-assed solutions and wants a clean one.

Comment: There can *never* be a clean solution, due to type erasure.  There is not really any such thing as a `Class<GenericClass<SomeType>>`; the best thing you can do is cast a `Class<GenericClass>` to it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman What does this have to do with type erasure? `Class<List<String>>` is a legitimate type and, for example, the return type of `newInstance` for such a var is `List<String>`. The only issue is how to cast the `List.class` literal to it.

Comment: A `Class` is a runtime representation of a type, and at runtime, there are no generic types.  Any `Class<List<String>>` *must* satisfy `listStringClass.equals(List.class)`.  See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71585/how-to-get-parametrized-class-instance

Answer (score 0):

Since type erasure in Java generic, result of call "getClass" on instance of "List<String>", would lose type argument "String", in another word, it might be impossible to get "Class<List<String>>". But you can do it in Scala:

```
scala> List("foo", "bar").getClass
res0: java.lang.Class[_ <: List[java.lang.String]] = class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
```

Comment: But say OP wants to assign to a variable `Class<List<String>> c`

Answer (score 0):

This satisfies your "no-instance" criterion, compiles and runs OK:

```
Class<ArrayList<String>> c =
    (Class<ArrayList<String>>) Class.forName("java.util.ArrayList");
```

This works due to type erasure: At runtime, `ArrayList<String>` is just `ArrayList`, and further `Class<ArrayList<String>>` is just `Class`.